# I have my own source code to make more Facebook followers or Making a Facebook followers to Follow my Facebook Profile

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here's what I've got so far, but I'm getting an error

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const userId = '';
const token = '';

const url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/${userId}/subscribers?access_token=${token}';

axios
  .post(url)
  .then((response) => {
    // Handle the successful follow response here
    console.log('Followed successfully:', response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle errors here
    console.error('Error following user/page:', error.message);
  });
```

This is the error
Error following user/page Request failed with status code 400

Help me to fix That code for getting more Facebook followers This is for educational purposes

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v18.0/user/subscribers: _"This endpoint was removed as of version 2.0 of the Graph API."_